# Cannot select latest uploaded version to add to testflight

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I cannot select the latest version I have uploaded to seed to beta in external testing. First of all whenever I upload a build two version appearing, that have upload time difference of 5 to 15 minutes between them. One of them gets changed from processing to normal available state, but other does not. But now selecting the available build also selects the processing one and my selection is blocked and I cannot select the OK button because probably my selection is blocked by the processing one. I think it is UI frontend issue at itunesconnect side but it could be something I am doing wrong. Please help me if anyone has been able to tackle this issue if they faced. Please see checkout the attached image.

**Update:**

I Included `<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>` in my subsequent builds that I uploaded according to the new Export compliance message on the iTunes Connect home page. I am still facing the issue. I have contacted Apple Dev support, will keep you updated if I find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Did you try on Safari ?

Comment: @NicolasBraun Yes I have that as my default browser. Also have tried with Safari on iPad running iOS 9.0.1 also tried on windows PC running Chrome browser. I have update the original question. P.S.

Comment: @IshaanSejwal many times this issue coming....try with another browser and i solved this problem with upload app using Application Loder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been mysteriously solved by uploading the application from Application Loader with Aspera turned off instead of using Xcode's organizer window as suggested by Apple Developer support. Make sure you add: `<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>` in your info.plist file before archiving the build. Although mysteriously my previously uploaded builds have also become available for external testing.

Body of email that helped solve the issue:

> After further research, it looks like their may be an issue from your
>   end with your network while trying to upload to this app record in
>   iTunes Connect.
>
> First, for the best upload experience make sure that all ports and IP
>   addresses are accessible. Additionally, it’s important to make sure
>   the internet connection is very good, and that there are no firewalls
>   blocking the uploads. More information can be found here:
>
> http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/itc8e7ec5a60
>
> Second, it may be beneficial to try using the latest version of
>   Application Loader. Please note that you can export your project from
>   Xcode to upload through Application Loader. As a temporary workaround,
>   once you have Application Loader open, you can go to the File menus
>   and select the following:
>
> Application Loader > Preferences
>
> Then, select Advanced, and as a temporary workaround you can try
>   deselecting Aspera and upload the build again. You can follow the
>   steps below to use the latest version of Application Loader.
>
> 1. Download the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store:
>
> -http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/itc8e7ec5a60
>
> 2. Open the latest version of Xcode
> 3. Go to the File menu and select Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader
>
> Lastly, try uploading again to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello my dear friend there,*

I am also having your issue yesterday, I have this similar screen with yours:

[image: Similar Screen]

The build is duplicated which one of them are processing forever until today.

**My personal problem solving was:**

1. **Increase** my build number in Xcode so that I can reupload my build
   [image]
2. Rearchive the build then export for **iOS App Store Deployment** in **Xcode Organizer**
   [image]
3. Reupload the build using **Application Loader**
   [image]
4. Then try to reconfigure the build in **iTunes Connect**. For a while it is processing like usual, but it will not take forever, after one hour, the build will be available for testing.
   [image]

Hope my personal troubleshooting can be applied to your issue too.