# I have big issue with external test of TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I can't create a external testing version. "OK" button is disabled.
I need some help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit for Beta App Review in order to test externally, it says that just at the top..

Comment: It says need approval from Beta app review, because internal test not require review. Now, I want to select new version to create Beta app review but I can't. Do you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer here can solve your issue since I think it is similar: [Cannot select latest uploaded version to add to testflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740308/cannot-select-latest-uploaded-version-to-add-to-testflight/35907667#35907667)