# Missing Compliance status in TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

When I added my latest build for internal testing with TestFlight, I saw that it had a "Missing Compliance" status.

Is this a major problem? Why does this appear? How can I resolve this issue?

[image: Test flight status Missing Compliance]

Answer (score 938, accepted):

Unless your app is using some special encryption you can simply add Boolean a key to your `Info.plist` with name `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` and value `false`.

In code:

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

If you want to use the Xcode UI instead, head over to the Project > Target > Info panel, add a new "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" Boolean key with value `NO`:

[image: Screenshot of the Xcode view where to add the value.]

If your app is using custom encryption then you will need to provide extra legal documents and go through a review of your encryption before being able to select builds.

If you continue with selecting that version for testing, it will ask for the compliance information manually. Choosing "No" presents you with the plist recommendation above.

[image: iTunes Connect encryption export compliance alert for testing]

This is change has been announced in the 2015 WWDC, but I guess it has been enforced only very recently. See [this](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/302) and [this](https://chriswong1.gitbooks.io/wwdc-2015/content/Whats%20New%20in%20iTunes%20Connect.html) for a transcript of the WWDC session related to the export compliance, just to a text search for "export".

There are other similar questions on SO, see:

- [ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption export compliance while internal testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing)
- [Cannot select latest uploaded version to add to testflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740308/cannot-select-latest-uploaded-version-to-add-to-testflight/35794716#35794716)
- [ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption Cordova Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798375/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-cordova-build)

Comment: What is special encryption meant to be? Does using iOS keychain to store user's info count?

Comment: Under new iTunesConnect: Top menu > Features > Encryption

Comment: @mokagio I am using Https connection to consume data for the Application so Do I have to choose yes and submit any documents?

Comment: I use https fetch query to my api, should I answer yes or no? This sounds like a form for prism compliance.

Comment: I have this warning on my macOS app, even though I have the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption set to NO in my plist file.

Comment: @vigneshkumar, according to Apple's docs, these appear to be exempt: "Typically, the use of encryption that’s built into the operating system—for example, when your app makes HTTPS connections using URLSession—is exempt from export documentation upload requirements, whereas the use of proprietary encryption is not"  (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations)

Answer (score 182):

There's no longer any need to submit a new build or modify `Info.plist`; instead, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you are an **Admin** or **App Manager** role in App Store Connect.
2. Go to the **iOS** tab at the top left of TestFlight and click the **yellow triangle** next to the warning to provide this information within iTunes Connect:

[image]

3. Click the "Provide Export Compliance Information" link in the popup:

[image: Export Compliance Information]

Though, if you do choose to modify `Info.plist`, you'll never need to deal with this popup again.

Comment: @am_ I just tried it and it still works. You just need to click the "Provide Export Compliance Information" link in the popup. Post has been edited with the new screenshot.

Comment: There is no "Provide Export Compliance Information" link when I click triangle, I just get the informational text.

Comment: @RandyHill hmm, I still see the option with my app. It must depend on some other factors as well. Did modifying `Info.plist` work for you?

Comment: Turned out to be an access issue. I'm not an Admin (Developer+some other), and our Admin was who submitted the app. I had our Admin look at it in his account, and he was able to see/click the "Provide Export Compliance Information" link to resolve the problem.

Comment: @RandyHill thanks for the info -- I've updated my answer to explain that you need to be an Admin.

Comment: @am_ only users with admin roles can see the link

Comment: @Alexis.J - thanks for headsup! works as described when you are logged in as a user with admin rights.

Comment: Please edit that option can be seen only by the admins, I wasted 30 mins searching that option.

Comment: Hi @ReyanshMishra, sorry to hear that! The answer already does specify that you need to be an admin to do this.

Comment: "this is only available to admin accounts" - Incorrect. An App Manager can do it as well.

Comment: Thanks @DrorBar, I've updated the answer to specify this.

Answer (score 88):

In your `Info.plist`, Right click in the properties table, click `Add Row`, add key name `App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption` with Type `Boolean` and set value `NO`.

[image]

**Another approach to handle this**

Righ Click on `info.plist` and select open as and then click on `Source Code` Add this line in last of file before `</dict>` tag

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: one need to right click the properties table, and click 'Add Row' to do that, it took me a few minutes for find out :)

Comment: worked for iOS 16, Xcode 14.1

Answer (score 82):

Add following at the bottom of your `Info.plist`

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

Answer (score 17):

If your info.plist is shown as a property list (and not xml), the text you need to enter for the key is:
**App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption**

Answer (score 14):

Righ Click on **info.plist** and select **open as** and then click on **Source Code**
Add this line in last of file before
`</dict>` tag

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

and save file.

Answer (score 9):

If you are not using https in api calls, Please add this key "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" in your info.plist and set it to "NO"

Comment: HTTPS connections using URLSession—is exempt from export documentation upload requirements.

Comment: What is a URLSession? how do I know if I use it? I'm using React Native app with Fetch request and I have no idea - tried searching for it.

Comment: @DrorBar What did you end up doing here? I'm also using React Native (with Expo) and I'm not sure what I should be doing here. I'm making calls to my back-end over HTTPS.

Comment: @DarrylYoung I haven't found a specific answer but I'm pretty sure these kind of HTTPS calls are exempt from encryption requirements. You should be good adding the key.

Answer (score 8):

For **SwiftUI**

Normally there is no `info.plist` file. So use this way to add Non-exempt encryption key and value. Click on the + button as follows and type `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` as the key and `NO` as the value

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, if you can't see the "Provide Export Compliance Information" button make sure you have [the right role](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev22b9b2174) in your App Store Connect or talk to the right person (Account Holder, Admin, or App Manager).

Answer (score 3):

I just fund another way to do the same workaround. Because of I hadn' t the possibility to click on the yellow triangle (even if I have admin role), when you go inside testflight, then iOS (under "Build") instead of yellow triangle click the version number, another page will open and you will find on top right something like add compliance information (sorry if I am not totally accurate but I have the italian version but it would be really easy to find). Then you can do the same even if you, like me, are not able to click on yellow triangle.

Answer (score 1):

it simply indicates that you do not use encryption, it can be intimidating when you are a newbie but it is not a problem if you are sure that you do not use encryption

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Click On Manage**

[image]

**Step 2: Select, None of the algorithms mentioned above**, If you didn't use any description algorithms

[image]

**Step 3: Click on save**