# Missing compliance in upload date status in new group testflight when i add the build to test how to i solve this

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode8

i Get this error when i select the build to add into group testflight.
Please tell if any

[image]

But in my builds activity its showing on upload date... i am literally confuse about it please tell if any wrong in this...
[image]

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Compliance in Status when i add built for internal testing in Test Flight.How to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh)

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh/46050699#46050699

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's another way no need to submit a new build or modify Info.plist if you start Internal Testing **ASAP** without Uploading new build.

**Note :** If You will modify Info.plist, you'll never need to deal with this popup again.

You can simply go to the `iOS` tab at the top left of `TestFlight` and click the **yellow triangle** next to the warning to provide this information within iTunes Connect:

Below is the screen shot for the same :

[image]

Then click the "Provide Export Compliance Information" link in the popup & Select No And **Start Internal Testing** :

[image]

Comment: Ketan p @user1752054 already says that .. same solution its not an another method... anyway its useful to see these images..

Comment: @HariNarayanan Thanks for Correcting me.. I see now.

Comment: Is there another way to access the Export Compliance Information view? When tapping the yellow icon, mine doesn't provide a link. It only reads "This build is missing export compliance information." Could this be because I only have developer access?

Answer (score 10):

Complementary answer for those using React native with expo. To avoid this issue, put in your App.json:

```
  {
    "expo": {
      ...
      "ios": {
        ...
        "config": {
          "usesNonExemptEncryption": false
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

See [this link in Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/guides/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Select the iOS tab on the left toolbar >>> click on the missing compliance >>> update it >>> select "Start Internal test". This will change the status to "Ready for Internal Testing" and "Ready to Submit" for external testing.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the warning icon on Compliance and update it.