# Cannot provide missing compliance for testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded a version of the app I am working on to TestFlight.
Usually, I can provide missing compliance and let my testers get the build. For some reason now I cannot. Please look at the attached screenshot, which shows that I do not have where to provide the compliance.

[image]

Comment: Just click on it and you’ll be able to do it.

Comment: Well that doesn't work, obviously tried.

Comment: Normally you can click on it.  Today it is not working.  I expect this is an intermittent issue.  Use the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption tag in Info.plist and reupload your build.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know why this happened in the first place, but this solved my issue:
[Missing Compliance in Status when i add built for internal testing in Test Flight.How to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh)

Simply adding `NO` to `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` in `Info.plist` and then uploading the build again did the job.

**EDIT**
Eventually, together with my team mates, we understood this is a matter of restrictions, as my user on itunes connect did not have the right authority level.