# "Missing Compliance" TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am receiving a message of "Missing Compliance" when I try to submit my app in TestFlight, I've read other forums that say to add a Boolean key and that would solve the problem. However, when I add the code, the message remains. Can I please get a more detailed, step by step description of what I am supposed to do to get rid of this error.

Thank you!

Comment: check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh) with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:
In your Info.plist, simply add Boolean with a key name **App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption** and value `NO`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I'm new to this... How do I do this? is it through code? And once I do it, do I have to resubmit the app to the app store?

Comment: I was able to do what you told me... Now do I archive the application again and resubmit it?

Comment: Thank you very much by the way

Comment: archiving is not required.